# Form with dynamic select fields does not validate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here I basically setup 3 select lists

```
<label for="organization">Organization</label>
<select ng-change="setOrganization()" ng-model="form.organization" 
        ng-options="o.name as o.displayName for o in organizations" required></select>

<label for="board">Board</label>
<select ng-change="setBoard()" ng-model="form.board" 
        ng-options="b.id as b.name for b in boards" required></select>

<label for="board">List</label>
<select ng-change="setList()" ng-model="form.list" 
        ng-options="l.id as l.name for l in lists" required></select>
```

JS:

```
$scope.setOrganization = function(){
    $scope.lists = {};

    mySerivce.get('....', function(boards){
        $scope.boards = angular.fromJson(boards);
        $scope.$apply();
    });
};

$scope.setBoard = function(){
    mySerivce.get('...', function(lists){
        $scope.lists = angular.fromJson(lists);
        $scope.$apply();
    });
};
```

So when a organization is selected I get the boards and populate the second select field with the board data. Again when a board is selected all lists assigned to the board are fetched and the third select field is set with this data. The form remains invalid until all select fields have a selected value.

When the users changes the organization all fields are cleared. However the form.$valid object is still true. Where is the problem? The form has to be invalid when no value is selected since the fields are required. Any ideas?

Comment: You could set $scope.form.board = null in your get callback?

Comment: @ZackArgyle works greate! make this an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will verify that the select value is not set. Glad it worked.

```
mySerivce.get('....', function(boards){
    $scope.boards = angular.fromJson(boards);
    $scope.form.board = null;
    $scope.$apply();
});
```